# run cronitor on raspberry crontab

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

i'm trying to use cronitor (a server that monitors you cron jobs) on my raspberry pi zero.
The installation process for cronitor given in the doc fails when I run the last line:

```
# Install CronitorCLI
curl -sOL https://cronitor.io/dl/cronitor-stable-linux-amd64.tgz
sudo tar xvf cronitor-stable-linux-amd64.tgz -C /usr/bin/
sudo cronitor configure --api-key [[[my private key here]]]
```

I get this error

> /usr/bin/cronitor: 2: /usr/bin/cronitor: Syntax error: Unterminated
> quoted string

I guess this is caused by the incompatibility of the amd64 binary for raspberry? Is there another way to install this? Thanks

note: tested on raspberry pi zero and 4

Answer (score 3):

You probably already got an answer or given up.
Anyway for future reference:
Yes, the package you are trying to install is amd64, you just need to download the correct architecture one.
In the release section you can find the ARM package, it works fine on Raspi
https://github.com/cronitorio/cronitor-cli/releases/tag/28.7